# Switch focus from an input with enter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form in html, and i need to switch focus from the inputs with the enter key (thanks to my supervisor saying that most people doesn't know what the tab key is for)
I already try this solution

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    focusable: function (el, index, selector) {
            return $(el).is('a, button, :input, [tabindex]');
    }
    });

$(document).on('keydown', 'focusable', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $canfocus = $(':focusable');
            var index = $canfocus.index(this) + 1;
            if (index >= $canfocus.length) index = 0;
            $canfocus.eq(index).focus();
    }
    });
    </script>
```

And here's my form

```
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">
        <label for = "maquina">Maquina:</label><span class = "error"> * <?php echo $maquinaErr;?></span><br>
        <input type = "number" id = "maquina" name = "maquina" size = "20" tabindex = "1" value = "<?php echo $maquina;?>" autofocus><br><br>

        <label for = "gafete">Numero de gafete:</label><span class = "error" id = "eGafete"> * <?php echo $gafeteErr;?></span><br>
        <input type = "number" id = "gafete" name = "gafete" size = "20" tabindex = "2" value = "<?php echo $gafete;?>" onchange = "llamarGafete()">
        <br><br>

        <label for = "nparte">Numero de parte del componente:</label><span class = "error" id = "eNparte"> * <?php echo $nparteErr;?></span><br>
        <input type = "number" id = "nparte" name = "nparte" size = "20" tabindex = "3" value = "<?php echo $nparte;?>" onchange = "llenarUM()"><br><br>

        <label for = "um">UM:</label><span class = "error"> * <?php echo $umErr;?></span><br>
        <input type = "text" id = "um1" name = "um" size = "20" tabindex = "-1" value = "<?php echo $um;?>" readonly><br><br>

        <label for = "cantidad">Cantidad:</label><span class = "error"> * <?php echo $cantidadErr;?></span><br>
        <input type = "number" id = "cantidad" name = "cantidad" size = "20" tabindex = "4" value = "<?php echo $cantidad;?>"><br><br>

        <label for = "defecto">Defecto/Motivo:</label><span class = "error"> * <?php echo $defectoErr;?></span><br>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your event delegation is looking for `<focusable></focusable>`

Comment: Your supervisor is wrong. "Tab" to switch form fields is the convention used literally everywhere else on the internet, and is built into every single desktop browser. The enter key should be reserved explicitly for the form "submit" action. Overriding this interaction will be unfamiliar and counterintuitive for users, and possibly cause issues around accessibility. I STRONGLY recommend you do not waste time overriding the existing, sensible, default behavior of forms in favor of a solution which is WORSE.

Comment: @jered um, a lot of people do not know what tab is for.... not everyone is tech savy.

Comment: Also your code can not have external source and inline script in same block.

Comment: @jered I already try talking to him about that, but it didn't work, thank you anyway

Comment: @epascarello ty, with this and the other answer I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to prepend the the new focusable psuedoclass with the :

`$(document).on('keydown', ':focusable', function (e) {`